# What approach the IOS user of my app would prefer?

Tags: navigation, ios, tab, drawer

We started the redesign of the app following Android guidelines. We are now trying to port the design to IOS, however I am not so sure what to push.

Either a "Navigation Drawer" similar to the android app which brings consistency and will allow to grow.

Or a IOS bottom tab approach, which is more aligned with IOS guidelines, is more efficient for navigation.

Please a bit of guidance.

[image: Design 1]
[image: Design 2]

Answer (score 1):

Remember that consistency across platforms is an internal company benefit--not an end-user benefit, as few end users walk around using both iOS and Android (and those that do are obviously already well versed in both so it's not a big deal to be consistent).

You may have a very good internal business reason to keep the consistent, though (ease of maintenance, support, etc.)

As for navigating, studies have shown that the tab bar increased engagement with other parts of the app. Facebook is a notable case study of this. Google 'Facebook mobile tab bar' and you'll find several articles on it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a combination of both. The Tab bar seems crowded so you could move **Inbox** and **Me** to the Left sidebar. The Tab bar will have the main actions the user will need for your app **Scan & Pay**, Restaurants and **Offers**. The left sidebar will include the secondary actions for **Profile**, **InBox**, **Settings**, **Help** etc.

In summary:

1. **Left Sidebar:** Profile, InBox, Settings, Help
2. **Tab Bar:** Scan & Pay, Restaurants, Offers

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rizwan's answer, but instead you could try a tabbed "side-bar", like in Facebook's iOS app:

[image: Facebook's iOS App]